# MODX - Is there some sort of team enviroment or support?

Tags: repository, installation, versioning, modx, modx-revolution

And colleague and me are going to start a new project for which we want to use MODX. We are both almost new to MODX.

However, we want to use 'proper' team development, that is having own installations on our machines and a commons installation on a server that reflects the current state of development. We work on our specific tasks and pass these changes to the common version only once we the task is done and tested. Versioning should also be available.

Since MODX saves it content into a DB (did I get that right?) using standard versioning software (git, svn, etc.) does not seem so handy? Searching the internet also did not bring up answers yet.

Working on the same DB at the same time does not seem right. Neither does porting the DB changes manually.

How do you do that? Is there some plugins or a standard approach I did not find yet? We also considered using MODX-Cloud. Would that be a solution?

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few words about our workflow.

Usually we don't use git and work together on the same DB as well. Also we don't use chunks, snippets, etc. It's good enough for small and short projects. Only Vapor package. It helps to get whole site dump and to deploy it at another server like a simple modx package. It's really nice and fast.
In this case git is awesome for package's developing.

Sometimes we even don't use git at a large projects (it's good only if you want maximum speed).

But anyway git is nice. If you want to see snippets and chunks at git repo you can make them static (static elements keep their content in files not db).
So you can see you element's files at you git repo now. But you still have to transfer all the users, settings and other data via db. We also use Vapor for these purposes.

P.S.: But in the case that chunks consume a lot of memory and snippets returns only string and can't extend each other i don't think it's right way of developing.
P.P.S.: I recommend to use git for special packages at your project but build project and transfer it like modx package with vapor. Also i should mention that vapor script is written by Jason Coward and it is used at MODX Cloud for site transfer.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. We also got the idea to to use static resources/elements and packages in the meantime so it is good to know this has already worked out for other developers. We gonna give it a try with 'MyComponent' by Bob Ray. I will post about our experience.

Answer (score 0):

There are two extras for version control of modx content in DB:

1. http://modx.com/extras/package/versionx - saves changes in a separate table
2. http://modx.com/extras/package/simplxmygit - saves your MODx Elements to your GitHub account as versioned Gists.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is [Gitify](https://github.com/modmore/Gitify). From the README:

> The goal of Gitify is to provide a two-way sync of data typically stored in the MODX database, making it versionable with Git. To do this, it creates a representation of MODX objects in files. These files follow a certain human and machine friendly format, built from a block of YAML, followed by a separator, and then the main content (if there's a specific content field) below that.